# Prevent automatic stretching/scaling of axis in plotly when displaying Mesh3d

Tags: python, plotly

I have multiple polygons that I am displaying via the go.Mesh3d function from plotly. That works very well.
The only thing misbehaving is the axis scale. It stretches the polygons and looks wrong.

[image: stretcht polygons]

These are some buildings which are stretched on the z axis. **With what comand can I prevent that, so it is scaled 1:1?**
Here, as an example, how it approximately should look like (done with paint, so realy bad :D)

[image: what it approximately should look like]